# Swift iOS/Mac Catalyst: EKEventViewController and EKEventEditViewController do nothing when tap show all notes or end time

Tags: swift, eventkit, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventviewcontroller

I'm developing an app that manages events and I have an annoying problem that affects both EKEventViewController and EKEventEditViewController, some buttons wont work.

**On EKEventViewController**
 - "Show All Notes" does nothing when you tap over it both on iPhone/iPad and on Mac Catalyst App.

[image: iOS Show All Notes wont work on EKEventViewController]

**On EKEventEditViewController**
- "End time" can't be edited only on Mac Catalyst App (and the edit of start time is horrible).
[image: Mac Catalyst End Time wont work on EKEventEditViewController]

Can someone help me?

Comment: I see the same issues with changing start & end times on MacCatalyst.  Did you report the bugs to Apple?

Comment: Also you can crash the app by pressing Ends -> Time Zone -> typing CDT -> and then backspacing twice.  This leads to an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash as random places (e.g. in main() or in objc_release)

Comment: One more thing.  If you press Invitees it transitions to a blank screen with a transparent background.  You can still press the back arrow in the popover's header to get back to the 1st screen, but attempting to Add the event after that fails with `[General] Property of the type of object () is not yet supported.` error in the log.

Comment: Two more things.  EKEventEditViewController on Mac Catalyst also does not show the `Repeat` field, and it doesn't honor the user's local timezone so it shows the wrong end date for AllDay events.